# What could possibly cause a 404 error when the apparent url is correct in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have one page that returns a 404 error and it is just mind boggling why this is happening.  Please see this page:  http://www.cra63.com/eventos/

It's the first link, 50 Aniversario 2013.

All other links work. But, not this one. Crazy.  Is it a cache issue of some sort? I don't have a cache plugin installed, so I can't think of anything else.

When in the admin panel, the preview button loads the proper page with no problem. I have looked at the url 50 times and it seems to be correct.

Permalinks is set to /%post-name%/.

I'm not a novice although this apparently silly question makes me feel like I am.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE - This was resolved by simply renaming the permalink from:

50-aniversario-2013
to ...
50th-aniversario-2013

When using a different name, aniversario-2013, it wasn't fixed. So, all I can suggest is to rename the url/permalink.  But, this is definitely not a fix in my book. Call it a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Please duplicate page plus update URL accordingly (after you rename it).

You may enable WP_DEBUG - [visit this codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

One more idea, consider integrating an [optimization plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) and run it often. A [broken link checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/) is powerful too.

Ya neva know what the problem can be! Hopefully, it doesn't happen again...